# Android make Spanned containing link clickable in Toast

Tags: android, html, toast, clickable

Through a webservice I get an Error message containing a link (e.g.

```
Click <a href='blablabla'>here</a>
```

). I use fromHtml to turn it into a spanned and then show it in a custom Toast.
Inside the toast the text is shown and the 'here' is underlined, just like a link. However when I click it, it doesn't do anything.

How should I solve this? Is there any way to deduct the link from the xml (e.g.

```
<ERROR>Click &lt;a href='blabla'&gt;here&lt;/a&gt;</ERROR>
```

) so I can create a button to push 
which opens the link in a Webview?

Here's the relevant code:
My main activity

```
CommonCode.showToast(error, mContext, mViewGroup, true);
```

CommonCode

```
public static void showToast(Spanned toastString, Context context, View view, Boolean isLink) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup) view);

    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toastText);
    if(isLink == true) {
        text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }

    text.setText(toastString);

    Toast toast = new Toast(context);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Toasts were designed to place a small amount of information in front of the user for a short time. If you need buttons pressed try a dialog instead of a toast.